# Multiplying numbers

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge

Your task, is simply to multiply 2 integers given in input, separated by a ",". The catch is, you cannot use the multiplication operator "*", even if it is being used differently, or any loops whatsoever

This is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Test cases: *i dont know if you even need it! lol*

1,0 -> 0

5,6 -> 30

3920,549 -> 2152080

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate of existing challenges, but it suffers the same lack of clarity they did: "you cannot use the multiplication operator or loops" is not a well-defined requirement, on top of being [unobservable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11228)

Comment: Can I use `chr(42)`?

Comment: In addition to what _@pxeger_ mentions above, [do X without Y challenges are pretty hard to write proper challenges for](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/52210), and it's advised to avoid until you have a bit more experience writing challenges. It's also best to use [the Sandbox of proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback before posting it to main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
',¡`иO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXefQwoQLO/z//ze2NDLQMTWxBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf3WdQwsTLuzw/6/z31DHgMtUx4zL2NLIQMfUxBIA).

Would be 2 bytes without the restricted input-format:

```
иO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//wg7///@NLY0MuExNLAE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXC/ws7/P/r/I@ONtQxiNVRiDbVMQNRxpZGBjqmJpaxsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
',¡    '# Split the (implicit) input-string on ","
   `    # Pop and push both values separated to the stack
    и   # Repeat the first value the second value amount of times as list
     O  # Sum that list
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:eval("x"+chr(42)+"y")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp9IqtSwxR0OpQkk7OaNIw8RIU1upUknzf0FRZl6JRpqGmY6ppuZ/AA)

Comment: @DialFrost this is repeat, not multiply